# How to turn a list containing strings into a list containing integers (Python)

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, integer

I am optimizing PyRay (https://github.com/oscr/PyRay) to be a usable Python ray-casting engine, and I am working on a feature that takes a text file and turns it into a list (PyRay uses as a map). But when I use the file as a list, it turns the contents into strings, therefore not usable by PyRay. So my question is: How do I convert a list of strings into integers? Here is my code so far. (I commented the actual code so I can test this)

```
print("What map file to open?")
mapopen = input(">")

mapload = open(mapopen, "r")
worldMap = [line.split(',') for line in mapload.readlines()]
print(worldMap)
```

The map file:

```
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,2,3,0,0,2,
2,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
2,3,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
2,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,2,1,2,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,
2,3,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,1,3,2,0,2,0,0,3,0,3,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,3,0,1,2,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,2,
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,
2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,
```

Please help me, I have been searching all about and I can't find anything.

Comment: `[list(map(int, line.split(','))) for line in mapload.readlines()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: Did you want a list of lists? or just one big list?

```
with open(filename, "r") as txtr:
    data = txtr.read()
data = txtr.split("/n")  # split into list of strings
data = [ list(map(int, x.split(","))) for x in data]
```

fourth line splits string into list by removing comma, then appliea int() on each element then turns it into a list. It does this for every element in data. I hope it helps.

Here is for just one large list.

```
with open(filename, "r") as txtr:
    data = txtr.readlines()  # remove empty lines in your file!
data = ",".join(data)  # turns it into a large string
data = data.split(",")  # now you have a list of strings
data = list(map(int, data))  # applies int() to each element in data.
```

Comment: In my text file, it has multiple lines, and in the list, it shows \n (linebreak) how do I take that out, do I use line.strip("\n") or something like that?

Comment: nevermind, I want to remove \n from the list after its done, or it will be just one line of numbers.

Comment: line.strip("\n") to make a filename.read() a list... list.replace("\n", "") otherwise

Comment: when I use line.strip("\n") it gives me "[]", and I don't know where to put  list.replace("\n", "")

Comment: could you tell me a way to directly read a text file into a list OF INTEGERS, or remove the /n from the list but keep it in reading the file?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) built-in function in python.

```
L=['1', '2', '3']
map = map(int, L)
for el in map:
    print(el)

>>> 1
... 2
... 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you question, please find below a way you can change list of strings to list of integers (or integers if you use list index to get the integer value). Hope this helps.

```
myStrList = ["1","2","\n","3"]

global myNewIntList 

myNewIntList = []

for x in myStrList:
    if(x != "\n"):
        y = int(x)
        myNewIntList.append(y)


print(myNewIntList)
```

Comment: how would I remove the \n (line break) from the file whilst still keeping a new line?

Comment: (Also, when posting lots of code, encase it with three of these ` example: ```print("Hello") print("World") ```

Comment: as per your original question, you wanted to feed list of integers to PyRay. Solution above does that.
Am I missing something?
edited my answer to skip the new line character \n.

Comment: Please review the code of PyRay so you know where I am at, and understand what list I am using, its only one script! I need to read a text file, the contents of it is in my post, and I need it to replace the worldMap list in PyRay, making users be able to make their own maps easier, and even make their own games! Thank you for maintaining a calm, polite attitude!

Comment: I saw pyray.py in the shared git link. I think I know what you are trying to achieve. I would like you to answer a question first. worldMap in pyray.py is a 2-D numpy array and map file content shared by you is a list of integers. Are you sure you want to replace a 2-d array with list of integers?
I would suggest you to store worldmap in the map file in 2-d array only and use numpy for operations. Hope I am not misleading you.

Comment: Well how would I do it the correct way? That’s what I came here after all. I just want a way use PyRay as a functioning Raycasting Engine, I’m planning on making a program after this to visually make maps!

Comment: This is my understanding about what you want to achieve: "Replace worldMap 2-d array in pyray.py with a file that contains data for worldMap"
if that is what you want to do then store data in file as 2-d array and not as list of integers(as shared by you in original post).

Comment: so, I could turn the map file into a python file, then call worldMap from my main script?